# What magnitude stars were seen from lunar surface?

Tags: the-moon, apollo-program, astronauts, stars, magnitude

I've seen a claim* that some of the Apollo astronauts stepped into the shadow of the LM, raised their gold visors, and looked up into the sky to see the stars. If this is true any mention of what magnitude stars were seen?

*I have no idea of the veracity of this so I'm not going to include a link.

Comment: Related: [What did the sky actually look like from the moon?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/12256/195)

Comment: Do you ask for the magnitude during a lunar night or a day?

Comment: It suggest in the shadow of LM the main obstacle to see faint stars was scattering of light in the glasses of their helmets. The light was scattered from illuminated surfaces and reflected in helmet glass.

Comment: @ Heopps That is why I questioned the veracity of the claim.

Comment: How would they see stars with the lit lunar landscape in their view?  I don't even see the point in stepping behind the lander.

Comment: @LorenPechtel I'm just mentioning what I read. If the astronauts were in the shadow of the LM, with their backs to the LM (and the sun), and looked up so none of the landscape was in their field of view, would that eliminate reflected light that would limit their ability to see stars?